# Spring Integration with Hibernate & JPA - one table not created on boot , others are

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to add two extra tables to my existing Spring application. 
One is being created in the DB , but the other is not. I cant see any obvious differences to the JPA objects, and I have updated my DB properties for both. The only major difference between the tables is that one is mapped to a User's table in a bi-direcitonal relationship, the other is only one-directional.

Here are some code samples:

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="samplePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.bpc.services.domain.objects.User</class>
    <class>com.bpc.services.domain.objects.Account</class>
    <class>com.bpc.services.domain.objects.Transaction</class>
    <class>com.bpc.services.domain.objects.Payment</class>
    <class>com.bpc.services.domain.objects.Product</class>
   <properties>
       <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
       <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
       <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
   </properties>
```

data-context.xml JPA declaration:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.bpc.services.domain.repositories" />
```

product entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
```

payment entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment")
public class Payment extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    User user;
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rest_user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",
        targetEntity=Payment.class,
        cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();
```

Account entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rest_account")
public class Account extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    private Product appliedProduct;
```

Product table has been created , and is linked to an Account object on a *:1 relationship. But my Payment table is missing. The deployment runs fine, and the following is shown in the log:

> [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(payment), mappingColumn=id, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}

So the application knows about the Payment domain object and is using it in deployment, but when I attempt to use my service via a client the log shows this:

> DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'services.payment' doesn't exist
>
> [http-bio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
>
> [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'services.payment' doesn't exist

---

**UPDATE**
I tried running with 'create' instead of 'update' (as suggested in the answers) but with the same issue. there is an additional log entry related to the payments table now:

> 11:37:14.994 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.j.d.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Connecting to database for operation 'createStatement'
>
> 11:37:14.999 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter
>   table payment drop foreign key FK_5b79940uennr1ffusdus7cp2r
>
> 11:37:15.012 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table
>   payment drop foreign key FK_5b79940uennr1ffusdus7cp2r
>
> 11:37:15.012 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Table 'services.payment' doesn't exist
>
> 11:37:15.012 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter
>   table rest_account drop foreign key FK_ek67yy1rmivvpoofrc0603du9
>
> 11:37:15.513 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter
>   table rest_verification_token drop foreign key
>   FK_9i1lxa0i6h09fcobtm570hq7u
>
> 11:37:16.000 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter
>   table transactions drop foreign key FK_8i8qo3qvlyg4xaiqgrnbpfvvh
>
> 11:37:16.498 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter
>   table transactions drop foreign key FK_ce9ag0mlblwcp5n1bi1f2xwgs
>
> 11:37:16.993 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - drop
>   table if exists payment

When the payment repository is being loaded (without any exceptions) this is shown in the log:

> Identity insert: insert into payment (time_created, uuid, version, description, in, out, performed_by, user, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> 11:37:14.919 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl - Adding QuerySpace : uid = 
>   -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@b90c767]
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path :
>   timeCreated
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : uuid
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : version
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path :
>   description
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : in
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : out
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path :
>   performedBy
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : user
>
> 11:37:14.923 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG
>   o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl - Adding QuerySpace : uid = 
>   -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@74febc11]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a variable name in my JPA object that was also an SQL keyword

changed 'in' to 'money_in', and my table is created

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` instead of `update`? Note that `create` is **destroying** the previous data! See: [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) for details.

Comment: i hadnt tried this, but i think it may be the issue. The new tables would interfere with the current DB relationships. I will try this and start with fresh data. thanks for the suggestion